# Listen keyboard events on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Google Maps on my app and I use map for drawing Polyline on it.  I want to listen keyboard events on Google map so that say if I pressed Esc key while drawing Polyline , it should stop drawing  (it should reset DrawingMode). 
I tried this by 2 ways .
1. I added keyevents to its container :

```
 bindKeyEventsForMapButtons : function(btn){
        var me = this;
        btn.el.dom.onkeydown = function (e) {
            if(btn.getId() == 'drawPerimeterGoogleMap'){
                if(btn.pressed==true)
                    btn.toggle(false);
            }else if(btn.getId() == 'removeAllPerimeter'){
                    btn.setPressed(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, event gets fired when I have clicked on map. But not when I am drawing on Map .

2. By adding event to Map itself

   `google.maps.event.addListener(me.map, 'keydown', function () {
   alert('in keydown');
   });`

This never gets fired.`

And I dont want to listen key events on window or whole document as I have other components too in document

Any help? Thanks

Comment: The map doesn't have a 'keydown' event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a DOM event listener `addDomListener` and call `setDrawingMode(null)` on the `drawingManager`.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'keyup', function (e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if (code === 27) {

        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    }
});
```

Below is a working demo. Hope this helps.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/u7nrqevc/)</kbd>

**Edit**:

I realize that while this works for a rectangle, it doesn't seem to work with polygons because setting the drawing mode to null actually completes the overlay. In this case, you need to keep track of your overlay (in `overlaycomplete` event) and call `setMap(null)` on the polygon itself, in addition to the above.

```
var polygon;

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {

    polygon = e.overlay;    
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'keyup', function (e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if (code === 27) {

        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        polygon.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/a1j58c2b/)</kbd>